# Sample DashBoard Application in either C# or VB.net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dashboard

Though this is not a programming question i am sorry for that.

but i hope this quesiton will be help full for the developer who are or will developing Dashboard Appllication as [this one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/A-guide-to-create-6ab135b2) live demo over [here](http://www.visifire.com/samples/SalesDashboard/silverlight_samples_sales_dashboard.html).

i just trying to develop Dashboard application in vb.net but can't find any good example[not even in C#.net]......so please help me or suggesting me any good sample[either VB.NET or C#.NET and Doesn't using any third party control like VisiFire or etc] for dashboard style application. 
Thnank you so much..

Comment: You just answered your question. The link you provided contains source code for this dashboard app. Looks good to me.

Comment: @surfen, but i looking for app which does not contain any third party control....thank you so much for answering....that application contain ViciFire control

Comment: I see. I found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2006/06/14/631136.aspx and this: http://dashboarding.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check [PRISM Library](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).

It's a Patterns and Practices library for creating composite applications (composed from multiple controls)

It's reference implementation, the [Stock Trader RI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) is a dashboard-like application.

This library contains many quick-starts and samples in `Silverlight`, `C#` and `VB.NET`. It's been widely adopted too. I've been using it for quite long and It has helped me in learning `WPF` and designing my `WPF` applications.